# Removing Windows Phone target from Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was trying to add a web service reference to a Xamarin.Forms app when I noticed that there was no "Add service reference" option available when right-clicking the project's References. After some digging around I found that apparently you cannot add a web service reference to a project that targets Windows Phone 8. I am fine with removing Windows Phone 8 from my app as I really only care about Android and iOS. However, when I try to actually remove it, there doesn't seem to be an option to choose whether or not I want to target WP8 as you can see in the picture:

[image: WP8 not available]

So how do I actually remove Windows Phone 8 from my app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just unload the windows phone project? Right click on the project in solution explorer, unload project

Comment: I only have PCL, Android and iOS projects in my solution. So I have no idea why the WP target is even there in the first place.

Comment: It'll automatically add targets if you accidentally support them by targetting similar things.

Comment: So does that mean that there's no way of telling it exactly what I want to target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all Xamarin.xxx targets then uninstalling Xamarin.Forms from PCL and finally adding Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS targets again seems to fix the problem.